# Import database even if it exceeds the limit size

Tags: mysql, size, limit

I've noticed that MySQL accepts only 2,048kb size of database but mine is 3.45mb. Does anyone know how to import the database? I'm only using phpmyadmin.

Comment: "Increase the limits"? Anyway, what *actual error or symptom* is occurring? And in relation to *which command(s) or tool(s)*? Make sure to put this information in the question - error messages often make good initial search queries.

Comment: hi user 2246674, this is the error... "No data was received to import. Either no file name was submitted, or the file size exceeded the maximum size permitted by your PHP configuration. See FAQ 1.16."

Comment: That doesn't sound like a MySQL error at all. That sounds like a ["PHP upload size"](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+upload+size) limit. That is, PHP itself is *not accepting* the file before it even makes it to MySQL.

Answer (score 6):

Use command line interface  to do the import . I don't think there is such small limit for database size in MySQL . From MySQL documentation [SIZE LIMITS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/table-size-limit.html)
The limit may be if you are using phpmyadmin which may limit file upload size according to settings specified in **php.ini** file

**Syntax**

```
   $ mysql -u {DB-USER-NAME} -p {DB-NAME} < {db.file.sql}
```

If you want do import using phpmyadmin change settings in php.ini file

```
post_max_size = 10M 
upload_max_filesize = 10M
```

Comment: hi mhasan, yes I'm using phpmyadmin to import the database. If I use the command line, it will import the database right though it's 3.45mb? Thanks!

Comment: I already changed the settings in php.ini file but it didn't import the database. It shows the same error: "No data was received to import. Either no file name was submitted, or the file size exceeded the maximum size permitted by your PHP configuration. See FAQ 1.16." I will try to use the command line. Anyway, thank you mhasan for helping me! :)

Answer (score 5):

Here are simple steps:

1. Open **.sql** file
2. Select All (ctrl + A)
3. Copy All
4. Goto PhpMyAdmin
5. Select DATABASE
6. Open SQL tab and PASTE

Now wait for sometime.....

Comment: Not a viable approach for larger databases.